# How to draw four diamonds?

Tags: symbols

I want to insert something like [this](https://pixabay.com/es/cuatro-diamantes-logotipo-icono-1385510/) or something similar:

[image]

Any ideas? I've take a look to some commands, and none of them are useful.

Comment: One of these ❖ characters?

Comment: Yeah, one of this @Thruston

Comment: If you are using `xelatex` or `lualatex` you can just type it directly -- but you will need to be using a font that defines it, like "Arial Unicode MS".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass[border=1cm,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{bbding}
\def\ods{\OrnamentDiamondSolid}
\begin{document}
I am searching for this \ods\ around the world.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Another way to make (I've just found it) is to use \usepackage{pifont} \ding{118}

Answer (score 4):

With no font package, just draw four rules and rotate them:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\crosseddiamond}{%
  \raisebox{\depth}{\rotatebox{45}{\uprightcrosseddiamond}}%
}
\newcommand{\uprightcrosseddiamond}{%
  \begingroup
  \dimen255=0.707\fontcharht\font`A
  \vbox to \dimen255{%
    \def\smallsquare{\rule{.44444\dimen255}{.44444\dimen255}}%
    \hbox to \dimen255{\smallsquare\hfil\smallsquare}%
    \nointerlineskip\vfil
    \hbox to \dimen255{\smallsquare\hfil\smallsquare}%
  }%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

Abc \crosseddiamond\ def

\end{document}
```

The magic constant 0.707 is of course half the square root of 2, so the diagonal of the built square is the same as the height of a capital letter. The side is divided into nine, so the small square side is 4/9 of the side of the whole square.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here’s a somewhat more flexible and standardized version.  On XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, it fills in this glyph from DejaVu Sans, a font that should be included with the distribution.  You can substitute any font family of your choice, and use the bold and italic styles if they also contain the symbol.  It will be scaled to match your main font.  On PDFLaTeX, this document falls back to the glyph from the standard PostScript font, Zapf Dingbats, using the LaTeX new font selection scheme.

It both defines a `\BDiamondWCross` command and allows you to use ❖ directly.

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85} % Workaround for standalone 1.2 and LuaTeX.
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{iftex}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\ifPDFTeX
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{pifont}

    \DeclareRobustCommand\BDiamondWCross{\ding{118}}
\else % Assume the TeX engine supports Unicode.
    \usepackage{fontspec}

    \newfontfamily\symbolfamily[Scale=MatchUppercase]{DejaVu Sans}
    \DeclareRobustCommand\BDiamondWCross{{\symbolfamily ❖}}
\fi

\newunicodechar{❖}{\BDiamondWCross}

\begin{document}
I am searching for this ❖ around the world.
\end{document}
```

[image: I am searching for this ❖ around the world.]